# C# DPAPI must declare a body because it is not marked abstract

Tags: c#

I have no idea why i am getting the following error,"must declare a body because it is not marked abstract,extern or partial".
I actually follow the guide in the following site 'http://www.overclock.net/t/1293731/windows-data-protection-api-c-and-c'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DataProtection 
{
    class Program
    {
        public static byte[] Protect(byte[] userData, byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope);
        public static byte[] Unprotect(byte[] encryptedData, byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string plainText = "I have less headaches in the managed world!";
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);

            /* Call the method. The return value is a byte array of ENCRYPTED data */
            byte[] encrypted = ProtectedData.Protect(
                    plainTextBytes,                         /* our byte array to be encrypted */
                    null,                                           /* we can pass additional entropy in the form of a byte array (optional) */
                    DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser /* can also pass DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine */
            );

            /* Here we might write out the bytes in "encypted" to disk */


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protect and Unprotect must be implemented if Program is not an abstract class (and it shouldn't be). However, it doesn't appear that you're using them so maybe just remove them?

As it stands those two methods are abstract prototypes.

See here for a better example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx

Comment: hah thanks has been 9 yrs since i last work on c#. its totally new to me now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeff's comments, from the rest of your code, it looks like you do not mean to have your own `Protect` and `Unprotect` methods and are, instead, calling the ones from the [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. If that is the case, you do not need to declare anything in your class for those methods.